# An algorithm to find number of numbers in a given limit 'l' (0 <= l <= 10^16) with atleast one occurence of a single digit number 'n'?

Tags: algorithm, numbers, combinatorics

First of all, this is not a homework question. I was going through some combinatorial problems to solve algorithmically and I really just need to get a start towards solving this problem.

My initial thought was to declare an array of size 17 initialize it and run a loop to find the occurrence of a number, say '5' using a simple search. But the solution looks tedious and ugly.

1. Any thoughts on how to represent a big number (10^16)?
2. Is there a simple combinatorics formula/algorithm to solve this kind of problem?

Thanks.

Comment: You can handle this as a combinatorial problem, no need to write a program at all.  Would that do?

Comment: "Any thoughts on how to represent a big number (10^16)?" - *don't* do that. iterating up to 10^16 will take a loooong time. "Is there a simple combinatorics formula/algorithm to solve this kind of problem?" - of course there's, you've found this on a combinatorial site, right? :)

Comment: Also, I suspect you mean ... < 10^16, not ... <= 10^16, right?

Comment: I am actually in the process of writing a program to solve this. I just bumped into combinatorics and I have no clue where to look. Enumerative Combinatorics looks like a place to start, I was wondering if there was a specific area of Combinatorics that addresses such problems.

Comment: Hint that might be useful: the number of two-digit numbers which have at least one 3 is the total number of two-digit numbers less the number where we have both that the first digit isn't a 3 and also that the second digit isn't a 3.  "At least one" is the opposite of "none", and none is often easier to compute.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath This question (along with a few others) was asked by a Math student.  He asked me to program a solution for each one of them and I am just trying to start from the right place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you mean 0 <= l < 10^16 (not <= 10^16), all integers in this range have 10 digits (allowing for leading 0s).  There are 10^16 total values in this range.  I'd write the problem as:

Number with digit *n* = 10^16 - number WITHOUT digit *n*.

So how many ways can we not choose *n* in the 1's place?  9 ways.  How many ways can we not put an 'n' in the 10s OR 1's place?  9*9.  Following this logic, there are 9^16 ways of not putting an *n* in any of the 16 possible slots.

So your answer is 10^16 - 9^16.

If you actually meant 0 <= l <= 16, that range has only one more number, namely 10^16.  The leading digit of this number is 1, so if *n* = 1 you have exactly 10^16 - 9^16 + 1 values with a 1 in it.  If n != 1 then the previous answer holds.

Comment: "So how many ways can we not choose n in the 1's place? 9 ways. How many ways can we not put an 'n' in the 10s OR 1's place? 9*9." - I did not think of that. And yes I meant < 10^16. Thanks. +1

Comment: 1) you don't want leading 0, that causes problems if n is 0. 2) he didn't mean l *equals* 10^16. it's just an upper bound.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: Your point is that, for example, 23 is an integer in the range that has no zeros in it.  You're right, zero should be handled separately.

Answer (score 0):

Let:

> `G(m)` Be the number of values `i`, where `0<=i<=10^m` that contain the digit `n!=0`

As the previous answer says, when `n!=0`, the answer is:

> `G(m) = 10^m - 9^m`

So, `G(16) = 10,000,000,000,000,000 - 1,853,020,188,851,841 = 8,126,979,811,148,159`

When `n=0`, there are two possible ways to look at it.

1) Only digits after the first non-zero digit are counted
  2) All `m` digits are counted, even if the number starts with many `0` digits

For the second case, then the answer when `n=0` is the same as when `n!=0`.

> `F(m)` Be the number of values `i`, where `0<=i<=10^m` that contain the digit `n=0`

For the first case, then the answer is a little more complicated.  In an `m` digit number, the first digit is not 0, but the remaining `m-1` digits can be anything.  So, `G(m-1)` of the numbers defined by those `m-1' digits can contain a zero. Since there are 9 (non zero) possibilities for the leading digit,`F(m) = 9*G(m-1)`.

> Let `H(m,n)` Be the number of values `i`, where `0<=i<=10^m` that contain the digit `n`

Then:

> `H(m,n) = G(m)` if `n!=0`, and `9*G(m-1)` if `n=0`

where

> `G(m) = 10^m - 9^m`

Thus, `H(16,n) = 8,126,979,811,148,159` if `n!=0` and `H(16,0) = 7,146,979,811,148,159`